# How to check what buttons are selected and display all of them in a text field?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uitextfield

I am new at programming in Objective-C. I need some advice on how to allow the user to select 5 options out of 50 different ones (I will be using `UIButton` for that) and then display it in the `UITextField` for the user to see, and also check if it matches any results to qualify.

In a way it's like a card game, but using buttons for cards. I also need to make sure all 5 buttons are selected in order to display the result. I hope it's clear enough and someone could give me an idea or put me in the right direction on how to achieve it.

Comment: so you will have 50 buttons on your view controller and you need to select only 5 out of them?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Do you have any code you've started on for this that we could help with?  It's faster this way and helps the next person encountering your issue.

Comment: I have no code yet (all I have so far is a new project) because I am not exactly sure what is the best way to handle what I want to achieve.

Comment: There are many ways to do it. You must atleast start trying with online tutorials regarding how to setup simple  buttons on storyboard and play around .

Comment: Could you advice what would be the best way in your opinion so I could do some reading about it?

Comment: you need to know how to set a storyboard and how to make a simple app with it. Start from here:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/ios-tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-part-1

Answer (score 0):

what if you give each button a tag, and give them all the same selector when the are tapped. And in the selector you can check to make sure the correct button was pressed based on what the senders tag is?

```
#define BUTTON_TAG_1 1
#define BUTTON_TAG_2 2

-(void)makeButton1{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 20);
    button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button1.frame = frame;
    [button1 setTitle:@"Button 1" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button1.tag = BUTTON_TAG_1;
    [button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(action:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:button1];
}  

-(void)makeButton2{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 40, 20);
    button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button2.frame = frame;
    [button2 setTitle:@"Button 2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button2.tag = BUTTON_TAG_2;
    [button2 addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:button2];
}

-(void)action:(UIButton*)button{
    NSInteger buttonTag = button.tag;


    textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",buttonCounter++];

    switch (buttonTag) {
        case BUTTON_TAG_1:
            //do somthing
            break;
        case BUTTON_TAG_2:
            //do somthing else
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```